# Custom function to replace values in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function to replace outliers in a variable:

```
outlier_upper_replace <- function(x, level=1.5) {
  lowerq = quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE)[2]
  upperq = quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE)[4]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq
  outlier_upper = (iqr * level) + upperq
  x[x > outlier_upper] <- outlier_upper
}
```

I can't understand why `outlier_upper_replace(prod$varname)` is not replacing the value.

If I run the following code, which is a particular case of the above function, the value is replaced:

```
level = 1.5
lowerq = quantile(prod$varname, na.rm=TRUE)[2]
upperq = quantile(prod$varname, na.rm=TRUE)[4]
iqr = upperq - lowerq
outlier_upper = (iqr * level) + upperq
prod$varname[prod$varname > outlier_upper] <- outlier_upper
```

Any insights about why this is happening?

EDIT: Example

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
x <- c(-10, x, 10)

boxplot(x, main="start boxplot")

#function to bin-in upper outliers
outlier_upper_replace <- function(x, level=1.5) {
  lowerq = quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE)[2]
  upperq = quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE)[4]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq
  outlier_upper = (iqr * level) + upperq
  x[x > outlier_upper] <- outlier_upper
  return(x)
}

outlier_upper_replace(x)

boxplot(x, main="end boxplot")
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you run that fails, it seems to me that the code you gave should work.

Comment: Thank you I will provide a code sample

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
return(x)
```

to the end of your function.

The return value of an R function is the result of the last expression in the function body. Since you modify the vector in the last expression there is no result and you have to explicitly return the result.

Comment: @myst999, you seem to not understand how functions work. When you run your function, you need to reassign the output or assign it to another object. Try `y <- outlier_upper_replace(x); boxplot(y)` or `boxplot(outlier_upper_replace(x))` if you don't want to create another object.